# choose record which have max value of createdDateTime ax2012

Tags: datetime, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm writing a select statement,

I want to choose record which createdDateTime value is nearest.

For example

[image]

I want to choose second line, because it has max value.

How can i add this condition in my select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the example below:

```
Table   table;
;

select firstOnly table
    order by table.createdDateTime desc;
```

[Select Statement Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/select-statement-syntax)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Beware, it may take a long time if many records and no index on CreatedDateTime. Do not do on InventTrans!